# Format table in view MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have this evaluation model:

```
 public class Evaluation
    {
        public virtual int EvaluationId { get; set; }

        public virtual int CourseId { get; set; }
        public virtual Course Course { get; set; }

        public virtual int ComponentId { get; set; }
        public virtual Component Component { get; set; }

        public virtual int UserId { get; set; }
        public virtual UserProfile User { get; set; }

        public virtual int Grade { get; set; }
    }
```

And i have this view:

```
@model SGP.Models.Course

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            Username
        </th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var x in Model.Evaluation)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => x.User.UserName)
            </td>

            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => x.Component.NameComp)
            </td>

            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => x.Grade)
            </td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

I added a grade to component 1 and component 2 to user test1 and user test2, and it shows this when i run this view:

```
Username
 test1      -    Component 1  -  93
 test1      -    Component 2  -  80
 test2      -    Component 1  -  65
 test2      -    Component 2  -  60
```

And i want to show only one time the user, like this:

```
Username
 test1      -    Component 1  -  93
            -    Component 2  -  80
 test2      -    Component 1  -  65
            -    Component 2  -  60
```

So then i can only show a table with the usernames and onclick appear the components and their grades. How can i do this? Thanks

Comment: I think you should change your model in such a way that it represents a hierarchical data structure like you need it, not the flattened layout that comes out of the DB.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to virtualize the Ids. Just the main object:

```
public class Evaluation
    {
        public int EvaluationId { get; set; }

        public int CourseId { get; set; }
        public virtual Course Course { get; set; }

        public int ComponentId { get; set; }
        public virtual Component Component { get; set; }

        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public virtual UserProfile User { get; set; }

        public int Grade { get; set; }
    }
```

Use LINQ (I recommend you to do this in the controller):

```
@model SGP.Models.Course

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            Username
        </th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var x in Model.Evaluation.OrderBy(x => x.User.UserName))
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => x.User.UserName)
            </td>

            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => x.Component.NameComp)
            </td>

            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => x.Grade)
            </td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i've done what you said, in the view and in the controller, but the user keeps repeating, keeps showing the same way that is in the question

Comment: Did you do it like this: return View(Model.Evaluation.OrderBy(x => x.User.UserName))??

Comment: Btw, I just fixed a typo with my solution.

Answer (score 0):

Guess you could do it by having the foreach loop save the previous UserName in the ViewBag, and then have it check each time if it's the same, and if it is, return null.

```
@ViewBag.UserName = string.Empty
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            Username
        </th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var x in Model.Evaluation.OrderBy(x => x.User.UserName)
    {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @(ViewBag.UserName == x.User.UserName ? null : Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => x.User.UserName))
            @(ViewBag.UserName = x.User.UserName)
        </td>

        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => x.Component.NameComp)
        </td>

        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => x.Grade)
        </td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    }
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but when i run it, it shows the same way i said in the question, but with " = x.User.UserName" after the username

Comment: My bad, didn't add parenthesis to the line where it sets the ViewBag.UserName value, it should be like this: @(ViewBag.UserName = x.User.UserName)

Comment: @Erik: Fix a typo you have in foreach (var x in Model.Evaluation.OrderBy(x => x.User.UserName). Missing ending parenthesis